# iOS Swift returns a SQLite error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift2

I am trying to save some data in the SQLite in iOS but not able to open the database.

```
class DBManager: NSObject {
    var database: COpaquePointer = nil
    let dbPath = "myDB/mydb.db"
    override init() {
        super.init()
        database = openDB()
    }
    
    func openDB() -> COpaquePointer {
        var db: COpaquePointer = nil
        if sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
            print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(dbPath)")
            return db
        } else {
            print(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db))
            print("Unable to open database.")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error.

> 14
> Unable to open database.

How can I fix this?

OS: I have added the myDB folder into my code which contains the db file which I have created from SQLite Manager Firefox plugin

Comment: As the above link explains, you have a mismatch between your projects for that macro.

Comment: Did you even bother clicking the above link? They give many solutions there.